# Boundary coincidence implies coincidence of centers

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In the metric space $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$, if we are given $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ with the property that for some $r>0$

$$\partial B(x,r) = \partial B(y,r)$$

Then we can conclude that $x=y$.

This is clearly not the case in a general metric space, a trivial counterexample is the discrete metric space on a set with more than one element, since then for any $x,y$ we have

$$\partial B(x,2) = \partial B(y,2)=\emptyset $$

Even though $x=y$ might be false.

So we can define the following notion:

> 1. A metric space $(X,d)$ is called *injective* if for any $x,y\in X$, if there is some $r>0$ such that
>    $$\partial B(x,r)= \partial B(y,r)$$
>    Then $$ x= y $$

I am interested in classifications of injective spaces. Some preliminary thoughts:

1. Clearly any bounded, non-trivial metric space is non-injective, so a non-trivial injective space must be unbounded.
2. Any space with more than one isolated point is non-injective, so an injective space has at most one isolated point
3. It is also true for any normed space, since the boundary of a ball around a given point here consists of all those points at a distance exactly equal to that of the radius, away from the center.

Is anyone able to give a classification of injective spaces ? (A reference would also be appreciated if this is not a novel concept)

Comment: Your definition of an injective space is unclear. Suppose that $x\ne y$. Then what does your condition say? Does it say that there exists $r>0$ such that $\partial B(x,r)\ne \partial B(y,r)$? But this is true for all metric spaces which contain at most one isolated point. Is it what you wanted to know?

Comment: @MoisheKohan sorry, I added an extra "if" for no apparent reason. I have removed it, it should be clear now? The definition is meant to say that a space is injective if it is true that when the boundaries of any two balls of the same radius are the same, then the centers of the balls are also the same. So if $x\neq y$ then there cannot be any $r>0$ such that $$\partial B(x,r) = \partial B(y,r)$$